# How to check whether the response returned from server is image or not in Android?

Tags: android, image

In my Android app I am calling a URL for fetching images and that URL is also fetched dynamically. Sometimes what happened is that the server returns the path of the image but actually there is no image so can we put some kind of validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the url has finished loading try to decode the result into a `Bitmap` object with `decodeByteArray` or `decodeStream`, if it returns null the image is invalid.

```
byte[] data; // server response
// ...
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
if (img == null) {
  // invalid image
}
else {
  // valid image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution is using the Content-Type the server returns.  You can get this from [`HttpEntity.getContentType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContentType%28%29).  If it's an image, it should start with "image/".  If this is missing or inaccurate, there are workarounds.